# Dynamically create HTML table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have MultiSelect List & Get data using Ajax/Json.I need to add Quantity to Selected Products.Here i have put a Button after the Multiselectbox.First Select Multiple Products & then click the button i need to load that data to the Empty div as a Html table.

I have no idea how to get Selected Items to the Html table(Load Html table to the Empty div)

Here is my View

```
<select id="select-product" multiple style="width: 300px">
 // here is MultiSelectbox
</select>
<button class="btn btn-default " id="pick" name="Pick"   value="Submit">Pick</button>

<div id="product-load-tbl"></div> <-- need to load table here
```

Here is my Ajax Call

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        CallMultipleProducts();
        $("#select-product").select2({ placeholder: "Select multiple products here", });
    });


    function CallMultipleProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Orders/GetMultipleProducts',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg._prodlst.length > 0) {
                    $.each(msg._prodlst, function (index, item) {
                        $('#select-product').append($("<option></option>").attr("Value", item.ProductId).text(item.ProductName));
                    });
                }
            }

        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add an example of the returned JSON.

Comment: Hi. Look at this code in   http://jsfiddle.net/h967B/23/